# How do I slipstream macOS updates onto the installation thumb drive

Tags: macos

How do I slipstream macOS updates onto the installation thumb drive?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think you are looking for something like this? - https://github.com/munki/createOSXinstallPkg

Comment: Yes I believe so although I can't tell how to use it from the page you sent me to